# Changed value not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a textfield to change a value, which seems to work fine on one part.

```
Voornaam: <h3 id="title1">Test</h3>
      <input type="text" id="myTextField1"/>
      <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/><br/>
```

This is linked to this javascript function:

```
function change1(){
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }
   var title = document.getElementById('title1');
   title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
}
```

And this works without any problems and shows my changed value, however when I would like to display that same value somewhere lower in my html code, it does not show the changed value.

Here is a part of the code where the changed value does not show up:

```
  <section class="bg-green">
         <div class="block left wide">
            <article>
               <h1>testfile<br/><span contenteditable="true" data-id="school-name"><?php echo $schoolName; ?></span></h1>
               <br/>
               <p>
                  <strong>Geachte <span data-id="name"><?php echo $salutation; ?> <?php echo $lastName; ?></span></strong>,
                  <p id="title1">Test.</p>
               </p>
```

The part where it should show up is

```
<p id="title1">Test.</p>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your are using the id "title1" more than once. The document.getElementById will only find one (the first, if I'm not mistaken).

Use a class and iterate over the elements found by [getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```
   var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title1');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles,title => {
    title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
   });
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hppgjkbo/) of my solution.

Comment: Would you perhaps be able to show an example as the page does not fully translate for me unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinBosman I would, if you could supply a jsfiddle reproducing the error.

Comment: It's not fully working but you should be able to get the idea from this: https://jsfiddle.net/maukne4z/

Comment: @KevinBosman I added a working solution in the answer. Do you understand what the issue was?

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine. I do see what my issue was.

Answer (score 1):

You have two DOM elements with the same ID = title1

```
<h3 id="title1">Test</h3>
```

and

```
<p id="title1">Test.</p>
```

entered text should appear in the first usage of ID = h3 tag.
It is also invalid HTML when you use one ID more times

The solution:

```
Voornaam: <h3 id="title1">Test</h3>
  <input type="text" id="myTextField1"/>
  <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/><br/>

function change1(){
  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
  if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
   alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
  }
  var title = document.getElementById('change1result');
  title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
}

<section class="bg-green">
     <div class="block left wide">
        <article>
           <h1>testfile<br/><span contenteditable="true" data-id="school-name"><?php echo $schoolName; ?></span></h1>
           <br/>
           <p>
              <strong>Geachte <span data-id="name"><?php echo $salutation; ?> <?php echo $lastName; ?></span></strong>,
              <p id="change1result">Test.</p>
           </p>
```

Comment: I was unaware that this was not meant to happen. What would you suggest doing instead?

Comment: just rename p element's id to another value. If you have some CSS binded to that id, just change the selector to some class and that class to both elements (p and h3)
It is a good practice to use classes for styling (or better native tag names and combinations of various selectors) and IDs for JS binding. I am used to make sure that ID is unique in whole app so its a concatenation of view name or component name and unique element ID (example in your case: resultOfChange1)

Comment: change1 is not good name for a function, too. You should use self-describing names to minimise the need of documentation or comments